# How to add a character to the end of every string in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a list:

```
list = ["word", "word2", "word3"]
```

and I want to change this list to:

```
list = ["word:", "word2:", "word3:"]
```

is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

List comprehensions to the rescue!

```
list = [item + ':' for item in list]
```

In a list of

```
['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

This will result in

```
['word1:', 'word2:', 'word3:']
```

You can read more about them here.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension as others have suggesed. You can also use this code:

```
newlist = map(lambda x: x+':', list)
```

Comment: 1. you should not use the word list as a variable name because it represents python type 2. map does not return a list , type(newlist)==<class 'map')

Answer (score 0):

simple question but though a noob friendly answer :)

```
list = ["word", "word2", "word3"]
n = len(list)
for i in range(n):
    list[i] = list[i] + ':'

print list
```

strings can be concatenated using '+' in python and and using 'len' function you can find the length of list. iterate i using for loop till n and concatenate ':' to the list eliments.
feel free to post but thing of google first :P